# Delete line containing a specific string starting with dollar sign using unix sed

Tags: unix, sed

I am very new to Unix.

I have a parameter file `Parameter.prm` containing following lines.

```
$$ErrorTable1=ErrorTable1
$$Filename1_New=FileNew.txt
$$Filename1_Old=FileOld.txt
$$ErrorTable2=ErrorTable2
$$Filename2_New=FileNew.txt
$$Filename2_Old=FileOld.txt
$$ErrorTable3=ErrorTable3
$$Filename3_New=FileNew.txt
$$Filename3_Old=FileOld.txt
```

I want get the output as

```
$$ErrorTable1=ErrorTable1
$$ErrorTable2=ErrorTable2
$$ErrorTable3=ErrorTable3
```

Basically, I need to delete line starting with `$$Filename`.

Since `$` is a keyword, I am not able to interpret it as a string. How can I accomplish this using sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ sed '/$$Filename/d' infile
$$ErrorTable1=ErrorTable1
$$ErrorTable2=ErrorTable2
$$ErrorTable3=ErrorTable3
```

The `/$$Filename/` part is the address, i.e., for all lines matching this, the command following it will be executed. The command is `d`, which deletes the line. Lines that don't match are just printed as is.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting information from a textfile based on pattern search is a job for `grep`:

```
grep ErrorTable file
```

or even

```
grep -F '$$ErrorTable' file
```

`-F` tells grep to treat the search term as a fixed string instead of a regular expression.

---

Just to answer your question, if a regular expression needs to search for characters which have a special meaning in the regex language, you need to escape them:

```
grep '\$\$ErrorTable' file
```

Comment: Thanks! But I needed to delete `$$Filename` only. I needed the pattern to identify `$` as string and that I got here. I used the code `sed "/\$\$Filename/ d"`

Comment: use `grep -Fv '$$Filename' file`. `-v` negates the match